# My rails website redirects are failing in the test phase but seem to be fine in normal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what rails test:controllers gets me.

```
Failure:
StoriesControllerTest#test_adds_a_story [test/controllers/stories_controller_test.rb:42]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/stories/980190962> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/stories/980190963>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/stories/980190962" to be === "http://www.example.com/stories/980190963".
```

It seems to be offsetting the story url by one

This is the specific test that fails:
`assert_redirected_to story_url(@story)`

I tried changing what the test should say but that leads to either errors or failures.

here is the test that fails:

```
  test "adds a story" do
  assert_difference "Story.count" do
    post stories_path, params: {
      story: {
        name: 'test story',
        link: 'http://www.test.com/'
      }
    }
  end
  assert_redirected_to story_url(@story)
  assert_not_nil flash[:notice]
  end
```

and here is the controller action

```
  def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.save
        format.html { redirect_to story_url(@story), notice: "Story was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @story }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What do your controller action and the full test look like?

Comment: @spickermann , I edited the post to include that information.

Comment: Where is `@story` in your test coming from, and how is it set?

Comment: right at the start it does this: 
```
setup do
    @story = stories(:one)
  end
```
Is it pointing to the old first story? I'm going through a how to book as I make this so I don't understand a lot of the code lol. 

Thank you for walking through this with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned in the comments, when using

```
setup do 
  @story = stories(:one) 
end
```

then the `one` story that was created by the fixtures is assigned to `@story` and not the story that was just created during the test.

Instead, I suggest changing your test to:

```
test "adds a story" do
  assert_difference "Story.count" do
    post stories_path, 
         params: { story: { name: 'test story', link: 'http://www.test.com/' } }
  end

  assert_redirected_to story_url(Story.last)
  assert_equal "Story was successfully created.", flash[:notice]
end
```